# Should Zookeeper cluster be assigned to only one SolrCloud cluster

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I wonder about the best strategy with regard to Zookeeper and SolrCloud clusters. Should one Zookeeper cluster be dedicated per SolrCloud cluster or multiple SolrCloud clusters can share one Zookeeper cluster? I guess the former must be a very safe approach but I am wondering if the 2nd option is fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SolrCloud use Zookeeper to share cluster state (up, down nodes) and to load core shared configurations (solrconfig.xml, schema.xml, etc...) on boot. If you have clients based on SolrJ's CloudSolrServer implementation than they will mostly perform reads of the cluster state.

In this respect, I think it should be fine to share the same ZK ensemble. Many reads and few writes, this is exactly what ZK is designed for.

Answer (score 1):

SolrCloud puts very little load on a ZooKeeper cluster, so if it's purely a performance consideration then there's no problem.  It would probably be a waste of resources to have one ZK cluster per SolrCloud if they're all on a local network.  Just make sure the ZooKeeper configurations are in separate ZooKeeper paths.  For example, using -zkHost :/ for one SolrCloud, and replace "path1" with "path2" for the second one will put the solr files in separate paths within ZooKeeper to ensure they don't conflict.

Note that the ZK cluster should be well-configured and robust, because if it goes down then none of the SolrClouds are going to be able to respond to changes in node availability or state.  (If SolrCloud leader is lost, not connectable, or if a node enters recovering state, etc.)